# Cloud formation - Device index cannot be empty

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I have been trying to get two instances to join a domain and one be the dc. The code is from one of the templates however it doesnt let me run it with my modification.
I am getting the error DeviceIndex cannot be empty when the DC01 instance initiates.
This is the code for DC01

```
 {
    "Resources": {
        "DC1": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::Instance",
            "Properties": {
                "BlockDeviceMappings": [
                    {
                        "DeviceName": "/dev/sda1",
                        "Ebs": {
                            "VolumeSize": "40"
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "ImageId": {
                    "Ref": "BaseAmiId"
                },
                "InstanceType": "t2.micro",
                "KeyName": {
                    "Ref": "KeyName"
                },
                "NetworkInterfaces": [
                    {
                        "AssociatePublicIpAddress": "false",
                        "DeleteOnTermination": "true",
                        "DeviceIndex": "0",
                        "GroupSet": [
                            {
                                "Ref": "PrivateSecurityGroup"
                            }
                        ],
                        "PrivateIpAddress": "10.1.3.100"
                    },
                    {
                        "SubnetId": {
                            "Ref": "PrivateSubnetAZ1"
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "Tags": [
                    {
                        "Key": "Name",
                        "Value": "DC1"
                    }
                ],
                "UserData": {
                    "Fn::Base64": {
                        "Fn::Join": [
                            "",
                            [
                                "<script>\n",
                                "cfn-init.exe -v -c config -s ",
                                {
                                    "Ref": "AWS::StackId"
                                },
                                " -r DC1",
                                " --region ",
                                {
                                    "Ref": "AWS::Region"
                                },
                                "\n",
                                "</script>\n"
                            ]
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have created json formats in Network-Interface. So, it is considering the second one. Please try the below code snippet.

```
{
    "Resources": {
        "DC1": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::Instance",
            "Properties": {
                "BlockDeviceMappings": [
                    {
                        "DeviceName": "/dev/sda1",
                        "Ebs": {
                            "VolumeSize": "40"
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "ImageId": {
                    "Ref": "BaseAmiId"
                },
                "InstanceType": "t2.micro",
                "KeyName": {
                    "Ref": "KeyName"
                },
                "NetworkInterfaces": [
                    {
                        "SubnetId": {
                            "Ref": "PrivateSubnetAZ1"
                        },
                        "AssociatePublicIpAddress": "false",
                        "DeleteOnTermination": "true",
                        "DeviceIndex": "0",
                        "GroupSet": [
                            {
                                "Ref": "PrivateSecurityGroup"
                            }
                        ],
                        "PrivateIpAddress": "10.1.3.100"
                    }
                ],
                "Tags": [
                    {
                        "Key": "Name",
                        "Value": "DC1"
                    }
                ],
                "UserData": {
                    "Fn::Base64": {
                        "Fn::Join": [
                            "",
                            [
                                "<script>\n",
                                "cfn-init.exe -v -c config -s ",
                                {
                                    "Ref": "AWS::StackId"
                                },
                                " -r DC1",
                                " --region ",
                                {
                                    "Ref": "AWS::Region"
                                },
                                "\n",
                                "</script>\n"
                            ]
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It will resolve the issue